# can i synthesise Bis(tri-tert-butylphosphine)palladium(0) from Sodium tetrachloropalladate and tri(t-butyl)phosphine

Tags: experimental-chemistry, teaching-lab

can i synthesise Bis(tri-tert-butylphosphine)palladium(0) from Sodium tetrachloropalladate and tri(t-butyl)phosphine if so how do i isolate the product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it can be done by a two step process *via* $\ce{(DBA)3Pd2}$:

1. Prepare Tris(dibenzylideneacetone)dipalladium–Chloroform from sodium tetrachloropalladate by the method of Fairlamb and Tsuji$\ce{^{[1]}}$
2. Use that to prepare bis(tri-tert-butylphosphine)palladium(0)$\ce{^{[2]}}$

Note $\ce{(t-Bu)3P}$ is extremely air sensitive.

**References**

1. Jiro Tsuji and Ian J. S. Fairlamb *et. al.*, The Elusive Structure of Pd 2(dba)3. Examination by Isotopic Labeling, NMR Spectroscopy, and X-ray Diffraction Analysis: Synthesis and Characterization of Pd 2 (dba-Z) 3 Complexes , Journal of the American Chemical Society, 10.1021/ja403259c, 135, 22, (8388-8399), (**2013**).DOI: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/047084289X.rt400.pub2
2. https://patents.google.com/patent/CN101693725A/en